# APEX 5.0 theme roller issue

Tags: oracle-apex-5

Facing an issue with theme roller in APEX 5.0 for a client's application steps performed are as follows.

1. Logged in APEX and ran your application.
2. Enter the credentials to run your application.
3. The normal home Page has Blue colour side bar consistent with the Universal theme.
4. Theme roller and selected the style as Vista (Copy) and set as current, at that time the colour in the home page changes(sea green) as expected.
5. After exiting from the theme roller the home page changes to white colour (neither sea green nor blue).
6. Checked the console message and got the following error message.

"Failed to load resources: the server responded with a 12745698.css status of 503 (Service Unavailable)"

If i click on the 12745698.css file I get the following

top

192.168.1.45:8080

apex

```
 oracle/r/209/files/theme/42/v69

    12745698.css
```

I checked the APEX_LISTENER and APEX_PUBLIC_USER users are unlocked, the catalina.out does not give any error.

How do I troubleshoot the issue ? any leads?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.

I was using HTTP port 8181. When I changed the port to 8080 the theme roller was back up and running.